# How to clear an array in MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, arrays, mongodb, mean-stack

I have an emails object that contains an array in a mongodb database. However, when I try to use $set to make the array empty it doesn't work. How am I supposed to clear the array?

```
exports.clearEmails = function(req, res, next) {
  var listId = req.params.id;
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    return res.status(400).send(errors);
  }

  EmailList.update({'_id': listId}, {$set: {'emails': []}}, function(err,results) {
    if (err) {
     return res.status(400).send(err);
    } else {
      return res.status(200).send(results);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: what is the error which you are getting ? can you debug the value of the listId field which is getting populated ? is that value correct ? the syntax of $set looks correct.

Comment: Have you also tried using the $pull operator as `EmailList.update({'_id': listId}, {'$pull': {'emails': {'$exists': true}}}, callback)`

Comment: I tried the $pull operator, it didn't work either.